# python 3 exec() globals() and locals()

Tags: exec, python-3.6

I have four calls to the same script with different environments, and only the first three succeeded. The system provided reason for the failure as "Fibnacci() not found.", but it was not found in the previous three calls as well. Hence it is quite confusing why the first three calls succeeded?

```
def isFun():
    #testFibtest2.py
    with open('testFib.py') as f:

        exec('print(dir())',globals())
        exec('print(dir())',{})
        exec('print(dir())')
        exec('print(dir())',{},{})

        code = compile(f.read(), 'testFib.py', 'exec')

        exec('print(dir())',globals())
        exec('print(dir())',{})
        exec('print(dir())')
        exec('print(dir())',{},{})

        exec(code,globals())
        exec(code,{})
        exec(code)
        exec(code,{},{})
isFun()
```

and

```
def Fibonacci(n):
    #testFib.py
    if n<0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
    # First Fibonacci number is 0 
    elif n==1: 
        return 0
    # Second Fibonacci number is 1 
    elif n==2: 
        return 1
    else: 
        return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2) 

# Driver Program 

print(Fibonacci(9))
```

and output:

```
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'isFun']
['__builtins__']
['f']
[]
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'isFun']
['__builtins__']
['code', 'f']
[]
21
21
21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFibtest2.py", line 20, in <module>
    isFun()
  File "testFibtest2.py", line 19, in isFun
    exec(code,{},{})
  File "testFib.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(Fibonacci(9))
  File "testFib.py", line 13, in Fibonacci
    return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2)
NameError: name 'Fibonacci' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Python 3 documentation, in the 4th call, since both globals and locals are passed to exec(), the code is executed as if within a class. Then the Fibonacci is a method in that class, hence it cannot be called as Fibonacci(). As a matter of fact, with no way to create an instance of 'a class', we cannot call it properly.